# Does it help to filter documents by another property first before performing a geospatial query through Search API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, geospatial

In the Search API for App Engine, there is an option to query documents containing Geopoints by the distance from a given Geopoint. Would it improve performance or reduce costs if I filter the documents by another property like "city" before using a query that filters by distance of the entities represented by the documents from user's location?

Answer (score 0):

If adding a city filter significantly reduces the number of results (i.e. a large part of a search circle is beyond the city limits) then this filter will improve performance. On the other hand, if your search happens to be inside a city, adding this filter will degrade performance.

Comment: This is very interesting, can you link some documentation on how query order works with regard to optimisation?